# Ordering posts by day (not time) AND meta value

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a list of posts that is first ordered by day, and then within that day ordered user votes (stored as a meta field).

Would it be better to convert each timestamp to the day at the time of the query, or to create another meta field that stores the day? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: That's only applicable for grabbing posts from a certain day, not ordering by day. The only date-related option for the 'orderby' parameter is 'date'.

Comment: Better create a day custom meta.

Comment: Wait, don't create anything yet. I'm trying something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I've found. I'm using a filter to filter the ORDER BY on the SQL query generated by WP_Query. The filter is this [`posts_orderby`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby). And with it, you can write a custom ORDER BY for the query. I'm gonna show you an example.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby');

function posts_orderby($orderby_for_query) {
    $orderby_for_query = "LEFT(wp_posts.post_date, 10) DESC, wp_posts.post_title ASC";
    return $orderby_for_query;
}
```

The key here is the [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) function, it's a MYSQL function. With this, you can "modify" the date, so MYSQL uses just the first 10 chars, so it uses the year, month and day, and not the time, which I think is what you wanted.

edit: as pointed by adelval, the [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function could be used instead of `LEFT`.

You might need to remove the filter to avoid affecting other queries, you can do it like this:

```
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby' );
```

Add that after the call to `new WP_Query()`. I hope this helped, if you have any doubt, ask.

EDIT: Just as recommendation, it is a good idea to avoid hardcoding the DB prefix, you can get it with this code.

```
global $wpdb;    
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
```

Then, just prepend that to the table names. For tablename.column

```
$prefix . 'tablename.column'
```

By default, the prefix is 'wp_'.

To check the generated SQL query you can `var_dump($name_of_query->request)`

Comment: Somehow it just started working perfectly. Thank you SO much! What a brilliant solution. The bounty is yours :)

Comment: Wait, it shouldn't work magically, it should always work. Can you share the code to check?

Comment: I figured out it was because the meta field I was sorting by did not have a default value (of 0) so it would not included many posts in the query. Your code works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @TomásCot I have added a code (in answer) and it's not working. Can you check what I am doing wrong. I am sorting blog posts date wise and then within that date, by custom field "my_post_rating"

Comment: @Roberthue, you could try with `$orderby_for_query = 'LEFT( wp_posts.post_date, 10 ) DESC ' . $orderby_for_query;`

Comment: Did that, but it's listing posts by custom field value regardless of dates. Is my $args all right?

Comment: @Roberthue, you should ask yur own question. To debug, you can `var_dump($query->request)`

Comment: Sorry, yes I asked another question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159776/order-posts-by-date-and-then-by-custom-field

Comment: If you replace the LEFT clause in the answer by DAY(wp_posts.post_date) I think it makes for more readable code

Comment: @adelval, it's more readable but it doesn't work. DAY returns the day of the month, an integer between 1 and 31, which is useless in this particular case.

Comment: @Tomás-Cot You're right, my mistake. But then DATE (which gets the date from a datetime value) seems to be the right answer

Comment: @adelval, yes, that should work. I was using LEFT because I use postgre

Answer (score 0):

I am using a solution that mixes a meta field and a data as order parameters.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'meta_key' => '[your vote field]',
            'orderby' => 'date meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                            'key' => '[your vote field]',
                                            'value' => [what values],
                                            'compare' => '[IN - NOT IN, you decide]',
                                    )
                            ),
            'date_query' => array(
                                    'after' => '1 day ago',
                            )
            ));
```

Then you also have to add this to your functions.php:

```
function wpse159469_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    return implode( ' DESC,', explode( ',', str_replace( array(' ASC', ' DESC' ), '', $orderby ) ) ) . ' DESC';
}
```

and remember to add the filter before and after your query:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse159469_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
//query and stuff
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse159469_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
```

This solution works for me.