# Order posts by date and then by custom field

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, order

I am trying to do something like this one.
[Ordering posts by day (not time) AND meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159474/ordering-posts-by-day-not-time-and-meta-value)

I want to list blog posts ordered by date (not time) and then within that day, I want to sort them by custom field my_post_rating. This simply outputs posts ordered by rating.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
  'meta_key' => 'my_post_rating',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);

$new_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have also tried suggested solution but it did not worked. Please suggest what is wrong?

**Edit //** Var dump added

> string(344) "SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_post_rating' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC "

Comment: add a `var_dump` of `$new_query->request`, when using the code from the other question.

Comment: Added var dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  add_filter('posts_orderby', 'posts_orderby');

  function posts_orderby($orderby_for_query) {
        global $wpdb;
        $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $orderby_for_query = "LEFT(" . $prefix . "posts.post_date, 10) DESC, " . $orderby_for_query;
        return $orderby_for_query;
    }
```

This produces this query:

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_post_rating' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY LEFT(wp_posts.post_date, 10) DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC
```

Comment: Hey @Tomascot how can we make it weekly instead of daily.

Comment: `"YEAR(" . $prefix . "posts.post_date) DESC, WEEK(" . $prefix . "posts.post_date) DESC," . $orderby_for_query;`   


I didn't test it but it should be something like that.

Comment: it's showing same results. here is the vardump `"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_post_rating' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY YEAR(wp_posts.post_date) DESC, WEEK(wp_posts.post_date) DESC, wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC"`

Comment: It could be showing the same results, have you checked if the posts order ir right?

Comment: I think it's working. Earlier, my page was showing cached result. Has to clear cache from WordPress. Thanks Tomas. BTW how did you learn such good mysql. Can you suggest a good and easy guide for a mysql noob. ;)

Comment: The key is to know that MySQL has a lot of date functions builtin, so you just have to hit the docs, and the naming is great, so it's easy to know what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will look into the docs. BTW that's how I learn WordPress. But I never really cared about learning mysql functions and syntax because WordPress functions does that dirty work for me. Thanks. Have a nice weekend.